# Аналог await для libuv

Tags: c, async-await, асинхронность

Сейчас await сделал вот так

```
void rr_await(rr_context *c){
    while (uv_run(c->handle->loop, UV_RUN_ONCE) && c->ok==0);
}
```

Проверяем флаг в переменной каждый цикл. `rr_context` - структура с указателями на всё что нужно в процессе работы.

Есть ли типовой вариант для того чтоб дождаться выполнения асинхронной функции?
Если конкурентное событие вызовет тут же процедуру, которая ждет ответа - не будет ли проблем с переменными на стеке или всё объявлять в куче?

В такой реализации не получится ждать одновременно несколько тасков. Хотя есть идеи со счётчиком.

Comment: с libuv не работал, а документация довольно скудная, но то что ты делаешь выглядит как минимум подозрительно, а при конкурентном/многократном вызове `rr_await` для одного контекста почти всё наверняка полетит к чертям... скорей всего стоит использовать другие примитивы синхронзации; какие именно — зависит о деталей задачи, в таком случае не помешает [mcve] для экспериментов.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, синхронизация мне не нужна! await как парадигма служит не для синхронизации. 
от многократного вызова ничего не сегфолтнулось - ничего не зависло. ответов получил от сервиса столько же сколько и запросов.

но один контекст конкурентно вызвать несколько rr_await не может потому как ждет завершения первого

Comment: с обычным `await`'ом, как парадигмой, этот способ ИМХО ничего общего не имеет т.к. он блокирует вызывающий код, т.е. является обычным ожиданием какого-то события с event-loop'ом... хотя может быть я просто не понимаю, как именно ты это используешь... про опасность — опять же, не зная как именно ты это используешь, сложно оценить, но в моём представлении это почти наверняка зависнет при определённых действиях...

Comment: Приостанавливает выполнение этой функции, но прокручивает loop - поэтому программа может получать новые запросы.

Comment: Без понимания общей идеи обработки данных, которую вы реализуете и вашей структуры `rr_context` ничего конкретного посоветовать не удастся. А также, объясните, что именно вы называете тут "таском"? (это разные pthread или некоторая абстракция для цепочки вызовов асинхронных функций обработки, вызываемых в `uv_run()`)

Answer (score 1):

В языке Си аналога await нет и быть не может, за бедностью самого языка.

Приблизительный аналог можно получить, найдя или написав библиотеку для зелёных потоков и вставив переключение потоков там где нужен await. Код при этом будет напоминать код из С++, с поправкой на язык и на используемую библиотеку.

Если рассматривать язык С++, то там оператор co_await присутствует, и его можно использовать если подготовить правильную обёртку (да, обёртку надо будет готовить на каждую асинхронную операцию):

```cpp
auto uv_tcp_connect_async(uv_tcp_t *handle, const struct sockaddr *addr) {
    struct awaiter : uv_connect_t {
        // копия параметров, она понадобится
        uv_tcp_t *handle;
        const struct sockaddr *addr;

        int status;
        std::coroutine_handle<> handle;

        bool await_ready() { return false; } // всегда вызываем await_suspend
        int await_resume() { return status; } // поле status - это результат оператора co_await
        bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
            handle = h;
            int status = uv_tcp_connect(this, handle, addr, callback);
            if (status >= 0) {
                // Важно: никаких обращений к this после успешного вызова uv_tcp_connect!
                // На данный момент awaiter может быть уже уничтожен
                return true;
            }
            
            this->status = status;
            return false;
        }

        static void callback(uv_connect_t *req, int status) {
            awaiter *a = static_cast<awaiter *>(req);
            a->status = status;
            a->handle.resume();
        }
    } a;

    a.handle = handle;
    a.addr = addr;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: мне наверное не нужен нативный await из плюсов. чтотто более сишное хочу придумать

Comment: @eri ищите тогда библиотеку. Я только boost context знаю, но это снова плюсы

Answer (score 1):

На Си как таковом асинхронности, к сожалению, нет. Зато есть на С++, который не особо отличается синтаксисом от Си. Можете попробовать переписать на нем. Вот пара статей по этой теме: https://proglib.io/p/asynchrony

https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/575062/

По поводу последнего, если я всё правильно понял, то лучше ограничить доступ к процедуре на время работы с переменной

Comment: Насчет Си, это сильное заявление. Посмотрите на [makecontext/swapcontext](https://linux.die.net/man/3/swapcontext), с помощью которых можно делать coroutines и прочие умодробительные штучки (но в их пользе для реальной жизни лично я сильно сомневаюсь)

Comment: Настоящую асинхронность я не прошу. Вопрос как сделать чтоб исключить проблемы с повторный заходом вфуекцию и как сделать что-то лучше чем установка флага в колбэке